# HTML report between different jobs?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have multiple deployment jobs which executes the same downstream testing job. 
I would like to attach the HTML report generated by the Testing job to the build report of the upstream deployment job. Is it possible ? How ?

Example:

```
Deploy_Dev -> AutoamtedTest  (Environemt=Dev)
Deploy_QA -> AutoamtedTest   (Environemt=Qa)
Deploy_PQA -> AutoamtedTest (Environemt=PQA)
```

in the example above, AutmatedTest build report will show the HTML report per each build, I would like to be able attaching this report to the upstream build report as well ....

Note: All jobs using the same master, yet, not necessary they will shall be executed in the same slave ..

THX.

Comment: This sound like a job for the ArtifactArchiver, see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/ (`archive` and `unarchive`)

Comment: required some twining, yet, it did the job